# Installing ANCOMBC without bioconductor on R 3.6 or any version less than R 4.0

Tags: r, installation

I noticed that having a minimum Bioconductor version of 3.12 and R 4.0 is mandatory for installing ANCOMBC. However I did install it on R 3.6 by doing the following:

1. Install all dependencies of ANCOMBC using Bioconductor version 3.10 (compatible with R 3.6)
2. Download the source tar.gz from https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/ANCOMBC.html
3. ```
   sudo R CMD install ANCOMBC_1.4.0.tar.gz
   ```

The above was done in a linux (Ubuntu) machine.

**Requesting any other recommendations for installing ANCOMBC on R < 4.0. Is the above recommended to do when package mandates minimum R 0f 4.0 but gets successfully installed on lower version?**

Comment: I would build docker images, e.g. based on `rocker/r-ver`. Then you can choose recommended versions of ANCOMBC and R. Even if it installed successfully, it is probably not yet tested, which is dangerous.

Comment: Thanks a lot danlooo for the inputs. Till now it seems to be working without issues but I will explore the docker option too.